# Can Representation Theory be studied computationally / numerically?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Can a subfield such as the representation theory of Lie algebras be studied computationally / numerically -- is there an interplay between the abstract and the concrete?  I would be grateful for an example, e.g. a reference to a journal paper.

Comment: 1) "RepLAB: a computational/numerical approach to representation"  Abstract: We present a MATLAB/Octave toolbox to decompose finite dimensionial representations  of  compact  groups ....  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.09154.pdf .   2) "Computational Topics in Lie Theory and Representation Theory" M.S. Thesis which developed MAPLE programs https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3194&context=etd